# suspend kubernetes cronjob on job failure to avoid subsequent job runs

Tags: kubernetes, cron

Whenever a job run fails I want to suspend cronjob so that no further jobs are started. Is their any possible way?
k8s version: 1.10

Answer (score 2):

you can configure it simply using `suspend: true`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job
spec:
  suspend: true
  parallelism: 2
  completions: 10
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: busybox
        command: ["sleep", "5"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Any currently running jobs will complete but future jobs will be suspended.

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/12/introducing-suspended-jobs/

If you are on an older version you can use `backoffLimit: 1`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: error
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
```

`.spec.backoffLimit` can limit the number of time a pod is restarted when running inside a job

If you can't suspend it however we make sure job won't get re-run using

> **backoffLimit** means the number of times it will retry before it is
> considered failed. The default is 6.
>
> **concurrencyPolicy** means it will run 0 or 1 times, but
> not more.
>
> **restartPolicy**: Never means it won't restart on failure.

Comment: I want to do this in a cronjob.

A cronjob creates job at specfied cron schedule. If the **job** created thus fails then the **cronjob** should get suspend so that no new jobs are started at next cron schedule.

Comment: It’s not possible you have to set the ‘suspend:true’ in cronjob thn it will creating new job. However you can set restart policy back off limit and other so if job gets fails it will get removed automatically form cluster. Cronjob create job fail in few second and it will get auto removed.